# Running my powershell script errors, while entering line by line into terminal works

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

i am attempting to create a power shell script that will help with automation (collecting data off a website).

I have several lines of commands saved in a script (.ps1), in windows powershell ISE (i have trimmed a small section below)

```
$ieObject = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ieObject.Visible = $true
$ieObject.Navigate('---')
$currentDocument = $ieObject.Document
$currentDocument.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("serialno")
```

My issue, is that when i copy paste each line by line from above into the terminal, it returns the result i want.

However when i run the actual script using the ise, i get various errors such as

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\--\--\script.ps1:13 char:47
+ $currentDocument.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById <<<< ("serialno")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IHTMLDocument3_getElementById:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I feel that the powershell script is executing differently to how I need it to, any help would be great. thanks

Comment: Add a  2 second delay after the navigate and try again.

Comment: @Drew thanks heaps for the advice! working for me now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance has not received all data yet. Add

`do { Start-Sleep -Seconds  1} until ($ieObject.ReadyState -eq 4)`

after instantiating $ieObject, that seems to do the trick.

I recommend against automating Internet Explorer, that's comprehensively last century technology. If you need to parse HTML document from a PowerShell script, using built-in Invoke-WebRequest is the easiest way.

Comment: Hi, thanks heaps for the response. I would definitely be using the webRequest feature however im stuck using powershell 2.0 on a VM environment, so i think this is the only way i can do it unfortunately. I have tried to insert the do-until loop that you listed, do i do this underneath instantiating $ieobject? or in the lines below. thanks

edit: i am using powershell 2.0, im uncertain if this pause is supported?

Comment: I used 
`Start-Sleep -s 2`, after my navigate as drew said above and it seems to be working now. thanks heaps for the help!

Comment: Sure, no worries - please upvote the answer if it was helpful ;)